# How to view docker logs

Tags: docker, containers

How to check docker logs for specific time using any sudo user.

like I want to check logs for 2022-02-02 from 00:00 AM EST till 01:00 AM EST.

So, I was trying to access logs using Sudo docker logs -f  but unfortunately it is giving me all the output.

Comment: Docker does not provide a mechanism for filtering logs by time. You could configure Docker to deliver logs into a system that does provide that facility, or if your application is logging timestamps you could probably write a tool to parse the output and find the logs you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/). There are 2 options of interest:

> `--since`
>
> Show logs since timestamp (e.g. 2013-01-02T13:23:37Z) or relative (e.g. 42m for 42 minutes)
>
> `--until`
>
> Show logs before a timestamp (e.g. 2013-01-02T13:23:37Z) or relative (e.g. 42m for 42 minutes)